# Matlab click zoom disables for the second time of the loop

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Consider the following example

```
ax(1) = subplot(2,1,1)
plot(1:100,rand(1,100))
ax(2) = subplot(2,1,2)
plot(1:100,rand(1,100))
hzoom(1) = zoom(ax(1));                                               
hzoom(1).Motion = 'horizontal'; 
hzoom(2) = zoom(ax(2));                                               
hzoom(2).Motion = 'horizontal'; 
zoom on 
linkaxes(ax, 'x'); 
waitforbuttonpress;
while 1
    [x,  ~] = ginput(2); 
    zoom on
    waitforbuttonpress;
    click_break = waitforbuttonpress;
    if(click_break)
        break;
    end
end
```

In the above plots for the first time of the loop the mouse cursor is magnifying glass and i can zoom into a data by simply selecting it 
[image]
and here we can see the data is zoomed in

[image]

but when i have clicked twice (for the ginput to get datapoints) and the loop runs in the next iteration the cursor doesnt magnify/zoom by selecting the specific data , I know we can also zoom in by scrolling but my scroll has developed some problem the magnification converges to centre data points so the only posibility is data selection through mouse click, am I missing any function in my loop?

Comment: It would probably make your life a whole lot easier to [add a button](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) that triggers `ginput` rather than using an infinite loop and hoping that your clicks somehow manage to zoom rather than trigger `ginput` again.

Comment: @excaza thanks for the tip I will try that , but this is just a random example in my orignal code i am taking unknown number of datapoints unless a keyboard button is pressed in while loop actually